# Trouble getting capybara-screenshot working with RSpec tests

Tags: rspec, capybara

I've looked through the Github documentations, looked for answers through google searches, and haven't been able to find an answer to why capybara-screenshot isn't saving any screenshots on failures.

Here's the setup I currently have for my application.

Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.14.1'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'pry'
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
capybara (2.3.0)
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
  nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
  xpath (~> 2.0)
capybara-screenshot (0.3.19)
  capybara (>= 1.0, < 3)
  launchy
capybara-webkit (1.1.0)
  capybara (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
  json
rspec-core (2.14.8)
rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
rspec-rails (2.14.2)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activemodel (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.14.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.14.0)
```

initializers/capybara.rb

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara::Screenshot.register_driver(:selenium_chrome) do |driver, path|
  driver.browser.save_screenshot(path)
end
```

spec_helper

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

# Include Capybara Capabilities
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'


# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

Capybara.save_and_open_page_path = "#{Rails.root.join("tmp")}/acceptance_tests/"

Capybara::Screenshot.append_timestamp = false
Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:rspec) do |example|
  "screenshot_#{example.description.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/^.*\/spec\//,'')}"
end

Capybara::Screenshot.autosave_on_failure = true
```

home_page_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

shared_examples 'home_page_tests' do |driver|
  context "When using the #{driver.to_s} driver" do
    before do
      Capybara.current_driver = driver
    end

    describe 'home page', :js => true do
      context 'the user is not logged into the application' do
        it 'displays login and sign in buttons' do
          visit root_path
          expect(page).to have_selector('.btn', text:'Sign i')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

describe 'Running the homepage tests' do
  it_behaves_like 'home_page_tests', :selenium_chrome
end
```

I've tried several variations to get this working, but I never am able to get a screenshot to save on failure. I can manually call the screenshot function, but given that the gem is supposed to autogenerate when a test fails, I feel something is wrong. Interesting though, I am able to get the cucumber portion of the Gem working just fine. Has anyone else had any troubles with getting capybara-screenshot working with RSpec? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you reduce your code samples down to a *minimal* example that re-produces the problem, along with any error messages you may be receiving (or specify that you're *not* receiving any)?

Comment: See if that makes it easier. Also, I'm not receiving any error messages at all. It acts as though whatever hooks that need to be registered are not registering properly.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, how to fix `unknown method render` ..)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest open an issue on [capybara-screenshot](https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot/issues/new) with a minimum reproducible example.